# jemmy3 status of development

Tags: java, swing, acceptance-testing, jemmy, jemmyfx

While I was searching for Swing UI-testing tools I came across Jemmy. The new version, Jemmy 3 has very promising lookup methods, according to [this tutorial](http://jemmy.java.net/Jemmy3UserTutorial.html) . On the other hand, I found no installation tutorial, no distribution jar either.

I cloned their mercurial repository and I could build 1 of the many subprojects. I could build them all if I imported them to NetBeans and resolved all the dependencies. Before I do so I'd like to know if the product is ready for that.

I tried to subscribe to their users mailing list but there was no answer yet. So, that's most likely a no: jemmy 3 is either dead or the team is on vacation. Does anybody know anything more specific about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jemmy v3 is very much alive - there is quite a bit of work going on on a constant basis.

The main customer of Jemmy v3 is JemmyFX (2.* and 8), which lives in OpenJFX repository:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/tests/file/tip/tools/Jemmy/
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/tests/file/tip/tools/Jemmy/

JemmyFX 1.3 is not being developed as Java FX 1.3 is not being developed. If you have a bug in JemmyFX 1.3, please submit it on jemmy.java.net - I will see what I can do. No promises, as if the fix takes too much time, I would not be able to implement it.

Shura

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, as I didn't know the project.

But if on one hand, they still mention support of JavaFX 1.3 in the JemmyFX part (1.3 is dead for a long time now), I see some activity in the Commits mailing list, so the pulse isn't totally stopped, apparently.

Note the FEST testing framework might interest you too. I hadn't an opportunity to really try it, but it looks good.

Comment: Jemmy 1.3 is not dead either.  There were commits just over 2 months ago; e.g. http://java.net/projects/jemmy/sources/jemmy3/revision/184

Comment: I meant JavaFX 1.3 is dead! :-) Sorry for the confusing phrasing.

Comment: I tried FEST and I found looking up custom components very difficult. I had more luck with Abbot which is good at finding components but selecting tabs of JTabbedPanes doesn't work.

I'm going to try jfcunit now. Also, jemmy is worth to try - jemmy3 looks the most convenient, but the older versions are worth a shot.